# Log level in boost unit test framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am using the boost unit test framework. I use the `BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE` function, and therefore I need to set the log level to at least `message`.

From reading the doc, I can do the following:

- I can add somehwere `boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.set_threshold_level( boost::unit_test::log_messages);` However, the doc indicates it to be generally considered bad practice.
- I can set the environment variable `BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL` appropriately. This is a bad solution for me, as I will distribute my code, and I do not have a good way to constrain the user to set this environment variable appropriately in their bashrc.

Does anyone know a proper solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution was simply to use the command line argument `--log_level` when running my binary.

Answer (score 0):

I personally liked the first approach you mentioned in the OP.
In my case I had something like

```cpp
BOOST_TEST(0 != 1);
for (auto i=0>; i<32*1024; i++)
    BOOST_TEST(i >= 0);
BOOST_TEST(1 != 0);
```

With a for loop emitting thousands of lines. I just surrounded it with

```cpp
namespace ut = boost::unit_test;
ut::unit_test_log.set_threshold_level(ut::log_warnings);

for (auto i=0>; i<32*1024; i++)
    BOOST_TEST(i >= 0);

ut::unit_test_log.set_threshold_level(ut::log_successful_tests);
```

Leaving the other parts of the test suite intact.